# javascript how to create object array with key as string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to mock response from server, therefore
I want the keys to be `1.0.0` etc.. instead of default indexes.
So the end results is like this:

[image: img]

I tried `{ 'versions': [ '1.0': { 'name': 'file-system'  } ] }`
And it didn't worked
I also tried:
 `{ 'versions': [ 1.0: { 'name': 'file-system' }  ] }` with same result.

I know that I can do it the hard way

```
let dummyResponse = {};
        (dummyResponse as any).versions = {};
        (dummyResponse as any).versions['1.0'] = { 'name': 'val'};
        (dummyResponse as any).versions['1.5'] = { 'name': 'val1'};
        (dummyResponse as any).versions['2.0'] = { 'name': 'val2'};
```

Thanks

Comment: In JS you can't use keys in arrays. Your example looks like it's already using an object, which is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Of course you can https://www.xul.fr/javascript/associative.php which is actually an object in JS

Comment: @Trueman the link you provided, basicaly says, that it's an object. It's not treated the same way as in php. OP can only create this way an object.

Comment: What leads you to think that anything on this screenshot is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to add into an array something that is not an int, string or even an object.

please try the following solution. You were missing the {}.

```
{ 'versions': [ { '1.0': { 'name': 'file-system'  } } ] }
```

:)

Comment: This doesn't get me what I want
I still have key as 0 and the value as { '1.0': { 'name': 'file-system'  } }

Comment: @Zakk Why not use a map then? Where the keys are the numbers and the values are the objects

Comment: @chevybow please create new answer with code snippet using map that I can get the same object result with it

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a key in an array, if you want store a version try this:

```
{
 versions': [
  {
    'version': '1.0',
    'name': 'file-system 1.0',
  },
  {
    'version': '1.1',
    'name': 'file-system 1.1'
  },
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just don't want to use a list here.

```
 const l  = {'versions': {'1.0' : {'name': 'file-system 1.0'}, '1.0.1': {'name': 'file-system 1.0.1'}}}
l.versions['1.0]{'name': 'file-system 1.0'}
```

Comment: I want the object to be exactly as the image because I am doing mock for server response

Comment: That is what the object is.